# dissmiss viewcontroller, memory isn't released.

Tags: ios

I have 2 viewcontrollers , one is FirstViewController and the other is SecondViewController  and I create both of them using storyboard. In FirstViewController  there is a button which is directed toSecondViewController  .

```
- (IBAction)click:(UIButton *)sender {
SecondViewController *secondController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
[self presentViewController:secondController animated:YES completion:nil];
secondController = nil;}
```

In SecondViewController, there is a webview.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webview


- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webview loadRequest:request];}
```

and also there is a button,click it can dismiss SecondViewController.

```
- (IBAction)click:(UIButton *)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];}
```

**My Question**

When I was in FirstViewController, memory is 9.1M, then go to SecondViewController, memory goes up to about 36.8M,then dismiss secondiewcontroller, memory goes back to aobut 24.8M.
Although I add the following code to secondiewcontroller, but it does not seem to be helping.

```
- (void) dealloc{
[self.webview removeFromSuperview];
self.webview = nil;}
```

I just want to best understand how to use the least amount of memory.Could anyone can tell me how to make the memory back to 9.1M after I dismiss the secondviewcontroller(release all of its memory)?

Comment: Is the `dealloc` method called when you dismiss the view controller? If not you probably have a reference cycle.

Comment: Have you tried the "leaks" instrument?

Comment: If you go back and forth several times, does the memory usage keep going up?

Comment: try [self.presentingViewController dismissViewController...]

Comment: @rmaddy Yes, the     delloc    method is called.

Comment: If `dealloc` is called then the view controller is being released. But something else could be sticking around. As @rdelmar asked, does memory keep going up as you go back and forth a few times? If so, use Instruments Allocations to find out what is using the memory.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes.it shows to me that there is no memory leak in my code but in System Libraries(JavaScriptCore) there is one(I am sorry but now I don't have enough reputation to upload images).

Comment: @rdelmar after repeating the scenario several times, memory will stop growing and keep at a stable value.

Comment: @rmaddy after repeating the scenario several times, memory will stop growing and keep at a stable value. Is it as expected?

Comment: Yes, if it's stable after showing/hiding the same view controller several times then that means there is no leak or reference cycle for that view controller.

Comment: @chrs I tried your advice but the memory was still not released. Thank you.

Comment: @rmaddy Do you mean there is nothing wrong with my code? But when I dismiss the secondviewcontroller why the memory does't go back to original 9.1M ?